# What are possible reasons for the page curl transition to hang at the end of the animation?

Tags: ios, swift, curl, uipageviewcontroller

I am using a `UIPageViewController` in my iOS app to transition between view controllers. The view controllers each contain an `SKView` and nothing else.

The page curl works perfectly fine, as you can see in the gif attached. Only at the end of the animation there is this strange shadow at the border of the screen.

[Gif of Page Curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyTfZ.gif)

[Shadow at the end](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2pqpbtk.jpg)

Here is the relevant source code, as requested:

This is the `ModelController`

```
import UIKit

class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageIsAnimating=false
let rootViewController:RootViewController!

var nextViewController:BookPageViewController?
var prevViewController:BookPageViewController?

var storyboard:UIStoryboard

init(rootViewController:RootViewController) {

    self.rootViewController=rootViewController

    let storyboardName = "Main";
    storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)



    super.init()
    nextViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(1)

}


func preloadViewControllers(index: Int, forward:Bool, oldViewController: UIViewController)
{
    if(index+1<Static.bookPages.count)
    {
        print("preloading next: "+(index+1).description)
        if(!forward)
        {
            print("taking oldviewcontroller")
            nextViewController = oldViewController as? BookPageViewController
        }
        else
        {
            nextViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index+1)
        }

    }
    if(index-1 >= 0)
    {
        print("preloading prev: "+(index-1).description)

        if(forward)
        {
            print("taking oldviewcontroller")
            prevViewController = oldViewController as? BookPageViewController
        }
        else
        {
            prevViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(index-1)
        }

        print("after preloading prev")
    }
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> BookPageViewController
{
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BookPageViewController") as! BookPageViewController
    viewController.bookPage = ModelController.Static.boboStory.bookPages[index]
    viewController.index=index
    viewController.rootViewController=rootViewController
    viewController.loadResources()
    return viewController
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    print("viewControllerBefore")
    let currentIndex=(viewController as! BookPageViewController).index

    if pageIsAnimating {
        return nil
    }

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        return nil
    }

    let returnViewController=prevViewController
    prevViewController=nil

    return returnViewController
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    print("viewControllerAfter")
    let currentIndex=(viewController as! BookPageViewController).index

    if pageIsAnimating {
        return nil
    }

    if currentIndex == ModelController.Static.boboStory.bookPages.count-1
    {
        return nil
    }

    let returnViewController=nextViewController
    nextViewController=nil

    return returnViewController
}




}
```

This is the `RootViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var recordings:[Int:Record]!
    var currentRecord=0
    var nextIndex:Int = 0
    var currentIndex:Int = 0

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated);
        setScrollEnabled(true)

        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    func setViewControllers()
    {

        let startingViewController: BookPageViewController = self.modelController.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = [startingViewController]
        self.pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [UIViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: {done in })
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "RootToParentModeViewController") {
            let parentModeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ParentModeViewController
            parentModeViewController.rootViewController=self
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(false, withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation.None)
        recordings=DataManager.sharedInstance.getRecordings()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Configure the page view controller and add it as a child view controller.
        self.pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .PageCurl, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)

        self.pageViewController!.delegate = self

        setViewControllers()

        self.pageViewController!.dataSource = self.modelController

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController!)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController!.view)

        self.pageViewController!.view.frame=self.view.bounds

        self.pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        // Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
        //self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers


        self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers


        // Find the tap gesture recognizer so we can remove it!
        for recognizer in self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers {
            if ( recognizer is UITapGestureRecognizer ) {
                self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                self.pageViewController?.view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    func reloadRecordings()
    {
        recordings=DataManager.sharedInstance.getRecordings()
        setViewControllers()
    }

    func setScrollEnabled(enabled:Bool) {
        for recognizer in self.pageViewController!.gestureRecognizers {
            if(recognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
            {
                (recognizer as! UIPanGestureRecognizer).enabled=enabled

            }

        }
    }

    func getCurrentRecord() -> Int
    {
        return currentRecord
    }



    func getCurrentLanguage() -> Record.RecordLanguage
    {
        return recordings[currentRecord]!.language
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var modelController: ModelController {
        // Return the model controller object, creating it if necessary.
        // In more complex implementations, the model controller may be passed to the view controller.
        if _modelController == nil {
            _modelController = ModelController(rootViewController: self)
        }
        return _modelController!
    }

    var _modelController: ModelController? = nil

    // MARK: - UIPageViewController delegate methods

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) -> UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation {
        return .Min
    }



    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionToViewControllers pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        print("willtransitiontoviewcontroller")
        self.modelController.pageIsAnimating=true
        self.nextIndex=(pendingViewControllers.first as! BookPageViewController).index!
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if(finished)
        {
            self.modelController.pageIsAnimating=false
        }

        if (completed){
            var forward=false
            if(self.currentIndex<self.nextIndex)
            {
                forward=true
            }
            self.currentIndex=self.nextIndex
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), {
                self.modelController.preloadViewControllers(self.currentIndex, forward: forward, oldViewController: previousViewControllers[0])

                });



        }// Turn is either finished or aborted
        print("didFinishAnimating")


    }


    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

And this is the view controller shown by the `PageViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class BookPageViewController: UIViewController
 {

    var bookPage:BookPage?
    var index:Int?
    var rootViewController:RootViewController?
    @IBOutlet var mainView: SKView!

    var scene:BookPageSKScene?
    var storyImageSpriteNode:SKSpriteNode?
    var flagSpriteNodes=[Int:SKSpriteNode]()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }



    func loadResources()
    {
        print("loadResources: "+index!.description)
        storyImageSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: bookPage!.pageImage)
        for (id, record) in rootViewController!.recordings {
            flagSpriteNodes[id]=SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: record.getRecordImage()!))
        }
    }

       override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("viewdidload: "+index!.description)


        scene=BookPageSKScene(bookPage: bookPage!, size: self.mainView.frame.size, parentViewController: rootViewController!, storyImageSpriteNode: storyImageSpriteNode!, flagSpriteNodes: flagSpriteNodes);
        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */

        scene!.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene!.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor();



        // Configure the view.
        mainView.showsFPS = false
        mainView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        mainView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true


        mainView.presentScene(scene)

    }


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true;
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }



}
```

Comment: post the code that you have used...

Comment: Please post some code when you are using transition and wha LLDB says.

Comment: I added the source code :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible reasons for the page curl animation to hang at the end of animation in UIPageViewController could be:

If you are doing heavy calculation in your viewDidLoad() function of the UIViewControllers, like if you are passing data to UIWebView or html string to UITextView/UILabel in the viewDidLoad() function.. Move those heavy calculation to viewDidAppear() function. Maybe this could help you. Happy coding!